# Finding the equation of a circle given one point and radius

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, circles

What is the equation of the circle which passes through the point $(0,2)$ with radius $4$ and whose center lies on the line $y = x$?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried first.

Answer (score 2):

The equation of a circle with center $(a,b)$ and radius $r$ is
$$(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = r^2.$$
You know $r=4$, $a=b$ and that $(0,2)$ is a point on the circle. Can you figure out $a$ from that?

Comment: I think it should be (x−a)^2+(y−a)^2=r^2 since y = x (a being either y or x) but I don't know what to do from there.

Answer (score 1):

So, the equation of the circle can be written as $(x-a)^2+(y-a)^2=4^2$

As the circle passes through $(0,2);$

$(0-a)^2+(2-a)^2=4^2$

Solve this for $a$

Answer (score 0):

The equation of the circle around $(x_0,y_0)$ with radius $r$ is
$$ (x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2=r^2.$$
Now with $y_0=x_0$ and $r=4$, this becomes
$$\tag1 (x-x_0)^2+(y-x_0)^2=16.$$
Since $(0,2)$ shall be on the circle, we knwo that
$$ \tag2(0-x_0)^2+(2-x_0)^2=16$$
Use $(2)$ to compute all possible values of $x_0$. Each of these gives you a valid equation if you plug it into $(1)$.

Answer (score 0):

I'll only post a start since you have not shown your work. Recall that the equation of a circle with center $(h,k)$ and radius $r$ is $$ (x-h)^2+(y-k)^2 = r^2. $$We are given that $r=4$ and you can substitute $(x,y)=(0,2)$ to get $$ h^2 + (2-k)^2 = r^2 = 16. $$Finally, since $(h,k)$ is on the line $y=x$, we have $h=k$, so we have $$ h^2 + (2-h)^2 = 16. $$Now, you can solve for $h,k$.

Comment: I tried expanding the equation and then factoring but somehow my mental prowess cannot afford to find the solution. I end up with an equation that's only factor-able by using the quadratic formula. Pardon me.

Comment: @ElCapitan Did you understand what I did so far? If so, then do you know how to use the quadratic formula? That's all you need. Using what I gave you, you get $$ h^2 + 4 - 4h + h^2 = 16 \implies 2h^2 - 4h - 12 = 0 \implies h^2 - 2h - 6 = 0, $$ so we get $ h = \frac {2 \pm \sqrt {28}}{2} = 1 \pm \sqrt {7} $.